# jquery select on click do something

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I do that when I'm selecting an option it will do something after I click the button?

This is what I have so far:

```
<select id="colors">
    <option value="">Select Color</option>      
    <option value="red">red</option>
    <option value="blue">blue</option>
    <option value="green">green</option>
</select>

<button>GO</button>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function(){
    $('#colors').change(function(){
        if ( this.value === 'red' ) {
            console.log('red selected');
        }
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/1dwboe6w/

Comment: you can add click event to `go` button   http://jsfiddle.net/1dwboe6w/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
$("button").click(function () {
        if ($('#colors').val() === 'red') {
            alert('red selected');
        }
    });
```

UPDATED FIDDLE http://jsfiddle.net/1dwboe6w/4/

Answer (score 0):

you can `add button click event` and get value using `val()`

```
$("button").click(function () {
        if ($('#colors').val() === 'red') {
            console.log('red selected');
        }
    });
```

**[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1dwboe6w/3/)**

Answer (score 0):

Just add to the `button`'s `onclick` event:

```js
$(function(){
    $('button').click(function(){
        if ( $('#colors').val() === 'red' ) {
            console.log('red selected');
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="colors">
    <option value="">Select Color</option>      
    <option value="red">red</option>
    <option value="blue">blue</option>
    <option value="green">green</option>
</select>

<button>GO</button>
```

Comment: @PraveenKumar appadila panna kudathu thappu.....i will do next time when you post correct answer ....Sorry......

Comment: @Bala Suvar... Nallavanga neenga.\

Answer (score 0):

html:

```
<select id="colors">
    <option value="">Select Color</option>      
    <option value="red">red</option>
    <option value="blue">blue</option>
    <option value="green">green</option>
</select>
<button class="btngo">GO</button>
```

jquery:

```
$(".btngo").on("click",function(){
    if ( $('#colors').val() === 'red' ) {
            console.log('red selected');
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use click event:

```
$(function(){
    $('button').click(function(){
        if (  $('#colors').val() === 'red' ) {
            console.log('red selected');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Attach `click` event to your button.

```
$(function(){
$('#go').click(function(){
    if ( $('#colors').val() === 'red' ) {
        console.log('red selected.');
    }
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danishfarhaj/1dwboe6w/5/)

just use function like this and it will work for you

```
$('#colors').on('change', function() {
```